# how can I correct this JavaScript adding function?

Tags: javascript, input, addition, validation

I have a form which takes six inputs (there are more but only these matter for now)

**original fare**

**original tax**

**new fare**

**new tax**

**fee**

number of guests

1. when "Calculate" is pressed I use javascript to **add original fare
   and original tax** to get the **original total**
2. then I **add new fare and new tax** to get the **new total**
3. now I **compare original total to new total**
4. **if original total is greater than new total** it should use one if several methods to finish doing the math I need and set the results to the display

i was originally testing everything using these values:

original fare = 1000
original tax  = 200

new fare = 800
new tax  = 200

fee = 150
number of guests = 3

which can bee seen here https://pnrbuilder.com/_popups/exchangeMyPNR_MATH_TEST_2.php
**(page only works in chrome)**
the above works exactly as expected but when I change the values to:

original fare = 949.83
original tax  = 321.18

new fare = 453.91
new tax  = 143.91

fee = 150
number of guests = 3

seen here https://pnrbuilder.com/_popups/exchangeMyPNR_MATH_TEST.php
**(page only works in chrome)**
this test uses the wrong if statement to finish out the rest of the math

I dont understand why this is happening as original total is still > new total so it should use the same method as the first example. I put in alerts to let me know exactly which if statement is being used to do the math and clearly the wrong one is used here but I just cant figure out why.

I know this is convoluted but could someone please help me figure out where my logic goes wrong?

---

**Here's the full function:**

```
function addMe(frm) {
    var orBase = Number(frm.box1.value);
    var orTax = Number(frm.box2.value);
    var nwBase = Number(frm.box3.value);
    var nwTax = Number(frm.box4.value);
    var fee = Number(frm.fee.value);
    var gsts = Number(frm.guests.value);


    var fltrd_orBase = orBase * 100;
    var fltrd_orTax = orTax * 100;
    var fltrd_orTtl = fltrd_orBase + fltrd_orTax;
    var orTtl = fltrd_orTtl / 100;
    var final_orTtl = orTtl.toFixed(2)
    frm.result.value = orTtl.toFixed(2)

    var fltrd_nwBase = nwBase * 100;
    var fltrd_nwTax = nwTax * 100;
    var fltrd_nwTtl = fltrd_nwBase + fltrd_nwTax;
    var nwTtl = fltrd_nwTtl / 100;
    var final_nwTtl = nwTtl.toFixed(2)
    frm.result2.value = nwTtl.toFixed(2)

    var e = document.getElementById("residual");
    var selectVal = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;



    if (final_orTtl <= final_nwTtl) {

        document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("MCOtable").style.display="none";       

        var undiff = final_nwTtl - final_orTtl;
        var diff =undiff
        document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML=diff.toFixed(2);
        frm.difference.value = diff.toFixed(2);

        var ppCost = diff + fee;
        frm.pptotal.value = ppCost.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=ppCost.toFixed(2);

        var ttlCost = ppCost * gsts;
        frm.totalcost.value = ttlCost.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=ttlCost.toFixed(2);              

        // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used
        if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                    // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                    alert('if 1 was used');
                }       

    }


    else if (final_orTtl > final_nwTtl) {



          if (selectVal == "residualX" || selectVal == "residualN") {

              document.getElementById("MCOtable").style.display="none";
              var diff = final_orTtl - final_nwTtl;

              var displayDiff = diff* -1;
              document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML= displayDiff.toFixed(2);
              frm.difference.value = displayDiff.toFixed(2);




              document.getElementById("forfeitInfo").innerHTML = "Beyond the cost above";
              frm.lost.value = diff.toFixed(2);
              document.getElementById("ppForfeitedDisplay").innerHTML = diff.toFixed(2);

              var ttlfForfeited = diff * gsts;
              frm.lostTTL.value = ttlfForfeited.toFixed(2);
              document.getElementById("totalForfeitedDisplay").innerHTML=ttlfForfeited.toFixed(2);



              var ppCost = fee;
              frm.pptotal.value = ppCost.toFixed(2);
              document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=ppCost;

              var ttlCost = fee * gsts;
              frm.totalcost.value = ttlCost.toFixed(2);
              document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=ttlCost;

                if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                    document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="table";
                }
                // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used 
                if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                    // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                    alert('if 2.1 was used');
                }
          }

          // this is the method that should be used below
          else if (selectVal == "residualA" ) {

              document.getElementById("MCOtable").style.display="none";
              var diff = final_orTtl - final_nwTtl;

              var displayDiff = diff* -1;
              document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML= displayDiff.toFixed(2);
              frm.difference.value = diff.toFixed(2);

               if ( diff > fee) {

                    var residual =  diff - fee ;

                    document.getElementById("forfeitInfo").innerHTML = "No additional cost. However,";
                    frm.lost.value = residual.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById("ppForfeitedDisplay").innerHTML = residual.toFixed(2);

                    var ttlfForfeited = residual * gsts;
                    frm.lostTTL.value = ttlfForfeited.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById("totalForfeitedDisplay").innerHTML=ttlfForfeited.toFixed(2);

                    //document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML=0;
                    frm.difference.value = diff;

                    document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=0;
                    document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=0;

                       if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                          document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="table";
                      }
                      // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used 
                      if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                        // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                        alert('if 2.2 was used');
                      }



                }
              else  {

                    var remBal =  fee - diff ;

                    var ttlcost = remBal * gsts;
                    frm.totalcost.value = ttlcost.toFixed(2);

                    document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=remBal.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=ttlcost.toFixed(2);

                    document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="none";

                      // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used 
                      if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                        // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                        alert('if 2.3 was used');
                      }                  
                 }
          }
          else if (selectVal == "residualM" ) {

              var diff = final_orTtl - final_nwTtl;
              var displayDiff = diff* -1;
              document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML= displayDiff.toFixed(2);
              frm.difference.value = displayDiff.toFixed(2);

              if (diff > fee) {   



                  var mco =  diff - fee ;
                  document.getElementById("MCOInfo").innerHTML=mco.toFixed(2);
                  frm.MCOamt.value = mco.toFixed(2);
                  //document.getElementById("differenceDisplay").innerHTML=diff;
                  //frm.difference.value = diff* -1;


                  frm.totalcost.value = 0;

                  document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=0;
                  document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=0;

                     if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                              document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="none";
                              document.getElementById("MCOtable").style.display="table";
                          }

                                  // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used 
                      if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                        // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                        alert('if 2.4 was used');
                      }
              }
              else {   



                  var remBal =  fee - diff ;

                    var ttlcost = remBal * gsts;
                    frm.totalcost.value = ttlcost.toFixed(2);

                    document.getElementById("ppDisplay").innerHTML=remBal.toFixed(2);
                    document.getElementById("grandTotalDisplay").innerHTML=ttlcost.toFixed(2);

                    document.getElementById("forfeitTable").style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("MCOtable").style.display="none";
                                          // this is just for testing to show which method was actually used 
                      if (orBase != "" && orTax != "" && nwBase != "" && nwTax != "" && fee != "" && gsts != "") {
                        // this is in its own if statement so it doesnt popuop while entering data
                        alert('if 2.5 was used');
                      }
              }




          }
    }
```

Comment: You post missing code for the function that you have problem with...

Comment: I will but its quite long

Answer (score 0):

```
var nwTtl = fltrd_nwTtl / 100;
var final_orTtl = orTtl.toFixed(2)

var orTtl = fltrd_orTtl / 100;
var final_orTtl = orTtl.toFixed(2)


if (final_orTtl > final_nwTtl )  {

}
```

This part seems to be my problem. the if comparison im doing here doesnt seem to like the `'.toFixed(2)'`  that I did above it for some reason. I changed it to:

```
var nwTtl = fltrd_nwTtl / 100;
var orTtl = fltrd_orTtl / 100;

if (orTtl > nwTtl )  {

}
```

Im still testing all the other features but this seems to be working as expected so far. I would still love to know why my use of `'.toFixed(2)'` causes two numbers that are clearly higher vs lower to evaluate to the opposite. and will accept any answer to that part of this question

Comment: toFixed makes the number a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed